# FOSUserBundle and Symfony 4.4.2 (lts) Problem

Tags: symfony4, fosuserbundle

I am trying to create clean new project using newest lts version of Symfony and I have this problem installing FOSUserBundle:

https://pastebin.com/bYYdY40E

I don't get it, why this simple config doesn't work?
I found tutorials showing the same working, but on Symfony 4.0

**Way to reproduce:**

```
composer self-update
symfony new s44_project --full --version=lts
cd s44_project
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
```

*I'm using PHP 7.4 to run cli commands*

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade to the `nucleos\user-bundle` which is a fork of the FOSUserBundle with Symfony 4 and 5 support:

https://docs.nucleos.rocks/projects/user-bundle/en/2.0.x/migrate_from_fos.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a temporary problem, since FOSUserBundle isn't compatible with twig version 3 yet.

**The solution is to limit twig version to <3.0**

```
composer unpack twig-pack
composer require "twig/twig:2.*"
```

Than install and configure FOSUserBundle, use `php bin/console cache:clear` a lot.